# MS Access finding customers that have previous year orders and don't have this year orders

Tags: database, ms-access

This problem is taking too long to solve on my own, so I hope someone can help me.

I have a simple MS Access database: two tables (Customers and Orders) and I need to get those customers, that have placed an order last year and haven't placed one this year.
This database is used to send CD's with information to clients. They subscribe once a year and then they receive a CD each month. What I want is to find those, who have forgotten to subscribe this year.

The table "Customers" is very simple: has fields like "Customer name","address", "e-mail" and so on. It is linked with table "Orders", where all the orders for each customers are stored. It is also pretty basic, has fields like: "Order Status", "Order type","Order year" (here, the year for which the order has been made is stored), "Quantity" and comments.

I tried to create 2 queries, each would gather orders for this and for previous year (by using that "Order year" field), but I cannot figure out what to do next, how to pull out the customers that have order in say 2015 and don't have one in 2016?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     SELECT a.*,b.orderyear
     FROM (select t1.* from customers t1 inner join orders o on t1.ID=o.CustomerID where o.orderyear=2015) a
     LEFT join (select * from orders where orderyear=2016) b 
     ON a.ID=b.CustomerID 
     WHERE b.orderyear is null
```

pulls out the customers that have order in say 2015 and don't have one in 2016

Comment: Looks like this works!!!
Thanks to all, I learned so much while trying to run each query. Every answer was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT C.* FROM Customers C
  INNER JOIN Orders O ON C.Id = O.CustomerID AND O.OrderYear = 2015
  LEFT JOIN Orders O2 ON C.Id = O2.CustomerID AND O.OrderYear = 2016
WHERE O2.Id IS NULL
```

It's going to get the customers that have an order record from 2015, and then it's going to set up an outer join on orders for 2016, which will return NULL for the 2016 orders fields if there is no match. The WHERE clause is then filtering out everything that does have a matching 2016 order.

Comment: I'm not that good with SQL, just replaced the names to match field names:

SELECT C.* FROM [AIP Customer] C
  INNER JOIN Orders O ON C.keyID = O.keyID AND O.SubscriptYear=2015
  LEFT JOIN [Orders] O2 ON C.keyID = O2.keyID AND O.SubscriptYear=2016
WHERE O2.keyID IS NULL

But this gives an error here: O.SubscriptYear

Comment: Should be "AND O2.SubscriptYear=2016" in the second condition of the left join rather than "O.SubscriptYear..."

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ".

Comment: Is the SubscriptYear field a numeric field or a text field? If it's the latter you'll need to put the value in quote marks: O.SubscriptYear = "2015"; O2.SubscriptYear = "2016"

Comment: Rephrasing.. You need to wrap the join expressions in brackets() like the example below: fashion:                                                                                                     select * from ((t1 inner join t2 on..) inner join t3 on..) inner join t4 on..

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it in Access, I would do it in stages:-

(1) set up a query (Query1) joining customers to Orders and selecting keyID where subscriptYear=2015. Might want to set Unique Values or use GROUP BY to avoid duplicates.

(2) Set up a similar query (Query2) for subscriptYear=2016.

(3) Set up a third query with Query1 left joined to Query 2 on keyID and specify Query2.keyID=NULL